# Running into issues mapping information with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been stuck on this problem for the longest time and haven't been able to make any headway on why I'm not able to map the values to the screen.

For testing purposes, when the code beneath the renderSurvey() console.log is commented out; the console will highlight two objects (one as an empty object and the second one as an array, after the data, is loaded from the database ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qzv8.png)).)

My running hypothesis is that the empty first object is causing the issues but I'm still stumped.

```
class SurveyList extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchSurveys();
  }

  renderSurveys(){
    console.log(this.props.surveys);
    return this.props.surveys.map(survey => {
      return (
        <div className='card darken-1' key = {survey._id}>
          <div className='card-content'>
            <span className='card-title'>{survey.title}</span>
            <p>
              {survey.body}
            </p>
            <p className='right'>
              Sent On: {new Date(survey.dateSent).toLocaleDateString()}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className='card-action'>
            <a>Yes: {survey.yes}</a>
            <a>No: {survey.no}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderSurveys()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ surveys }) {
  return { surveys };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys })(SurveyList);
```

Comment: The empty object should be causing a problem: you can't use the `.map()` method on an object, since it doesn't exist. When the code is not commented out, you should be seeing an error that says "TypeError: this.props.surveys.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render(){
    if(this.props.surveys && this.props.surveys.length){
      return(
        <div>
          {this.renderSurveys()}
        </div>
      )
    }else{
       return(
          <div></div>
       )
    }
}
```

It will check if `props.surveys` is received and fulfilled then try run `renderSurveys()` in `render()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Your solution seems to get it working perfectly. Still not exactly sure how that get's it to operate however or if I should use a similar set up going forward for similar applications